# Get bounds for annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to find the bounds for a list of annotations that I have on my `MapView`.

I see that in javascript you can add the annotations to the `FeatureGroup` of a layer and then get the bounds for that group.

However, I can't find this in the Swift SDK. How can I go about getting the bounds for a set of annotations?

Comment: Unable to get what actually your requirement is? Please clear it more accurately.

Comment: I don't understand how I can be more clear. I have a set of annotations, I need to know the bounds of a `boundingBox` that fits them all in

Comment: You can add some images so that it makes some clearance to us.

Comment: @DavidPilkington can you tell me if my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.annotations` property of your `MKMapView`, and get the **minX**, **minY**, **maxX**, and **maxY**, after that you can return those points as coordinates and add an overlay if you want

```
func getCordinatesOfRectAnnotations(annotationsArray:[MKAnnotation]) ->[CLLocationCoordinate2D]{
    let minX : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).x}).min()!
    let minY : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).y}).min()!
    let maxX : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).x}).max()!
    let maxY : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).y}).max()!

    var result : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: minX, y: minY)))
    result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: maxX, y: minY)))
    result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY)))
    result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: minX, y: maxY)))
    return result
}
```

**Full example code**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    var moscow: [Camera] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  40.741895, longitude:  -73.989308),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  38.80495938042258, longitude: -77.0273450631467),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  40.14404110473566, longitude:  -3.487181320896525),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  41.3425986835203, longitude:  2.093873366603475),CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:  -15.70239476628682, longitude:  27.486982547083358)]

        for (index,coordinate) in coordinates.enumerated() {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = "coordinate\(index)"
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        self.mapView.delegate = self

        let overlay = MKPolygon(coordinates: self.getCordinatesOfRectAnnotations(annotationsArray: self.mapView.annotations), count: self.getCordinatesOfRectAnnotations(annotationsArray: self.mapView.annotations).count)
        self.mapView.add(overlay)
    }

    func getCordinatesOfRectAnnotations(annotationsArray:[MKAnnotation]) ->[CLLocationCoordinate2D]{
       let minX : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).x}).min()!
       let minY : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).y}).min()!
       let maxX : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).x}).max()!
       let maxY : Double = annotationsArray.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0.coordinate).y}).max()!

       var result : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
       result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: minX, y: minY)))
       result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: maxX, y: minY)))
       result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: maxX, y: maxY)))
       result.append(MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: minX, y: maxY)))
       return result
    }

}

extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.lineWidth = 1
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
        return renderer
    }

    // Called when the annotation was added
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView?.animatesDrop = true
            pinView?.canShowCallout = true
            pinView?.isDraggable = true
            pinView?.pinColor = .purple

            let rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.detailDisclosure)
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as? UIView
        } else {
            pinView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }

}
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not coded in MapKit SDK, but it is very simple to get any bounding-box coordinate or your desire, for example:

1) Using coordinates array to find SouthWest and NorthEast of a bounding box:

```
let x = coordinates.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0).x})
let y = coordinates.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0).y})

let min_OR_southWest = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: x.min()!, y: y.max()!))
let max_OR_northEast = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: x.max()!, y: y.min()!))
```

This gives you coordinates as marked **red** below

[image]

If you need coordinates for other dots from image above, *just* use the 2 variables above `x` and `y`, for example if you need `nw` coordinate:

```
let nwCoordinate = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: x.min()!, y: y.min()!))
```

2) Providing another example using `MKPolygon`, which can also be used for a `MKPolyline` overlay

```
extension MKPolygon {
    var boundingBox: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, count: self.pointCount)
        self.getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.pointCount))

        let x = coords.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0).x})
        let y = coords.map({MKMapPointForCoordinate($0).y})
        let min = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: x.min()!, y: y.max()!))
        let max = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPoint(x: x.max()!, y: y.min()!))
        return [min.latitude, max.latitude, min.longitude, max.longitude]
    }
}
```